# Angular - Controller can't see my variables in html

Tags: html, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm here because i am not being able to make my controller see my html variables our functions, maybe you guys see something i dont =(

HTML:

```
<article ng-controller="CreateUserController">
  <div class="well">
    <center>
      <h1>Registrar</h1> <button ng-click="test()">Teste</button>
      </br>

      <form name="form">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback"
          ng-class="{
              'has-error': form.name.$invalid && form.name.$dirty,
            'has-success': form.name.$valid   && form.name.$touched
          }">
          <div>
            <input ng-disabled="true" type="name" required name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" ng-model="user.name">
            <p class="help-block" ng-messages="form.name.$error">
              <span ng-message="required">Nome esta vazio.</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </center>
  </div>
</article>
```

JS:

```
 angular.module('auth').controller('CreateUserController', [
  '$scope', '$http', '$location','$state','$routeParams', '$modal','$rootScope',"$resource","Auth",'UserCompaniesService',
  function($scope, $http, $location,$state,$routeParams, $modal,$rootScope,$resource,Auth,UserCompaniesService){

    $scope.signedIn = Auth.isAuthenticated;
    $scope.logout = Auth.logout;

    var Account = $resource('/accounts/'+$routeParams.id+'.json',
                             {},
                             { "show": { "method": "GET" }});
    account = Account.get({"account_id":$routeParams.id});

    //Not being seen
    $scope.test = function() {
      alert('teste');
    }
    $scope.user.name = account.name;//$scope.user is not being seen
    $scope.user.email = account.email;
```

user.html.erb

```
<article ng-app="auth">
  <div ng-view></div>
</article>
```

Can you guys please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could please provide some information as to what exactly you're experiencing? Please be as specific as possible. Are you seeing any javascript errors in your console? AngularJS is pretty good about outputting very specific information that will help you out.

Comment: where are you submitting the form? maybe you need to check the ng-submit directive and have a function assigned to it.

Comment: please put it into plunker: http://plnkr.co/

Comment: no errors, just that $scope.user is undefined. Its not just about the form, the button with ng-click test() isnt working either =/

Comment: Try changing "ng-disabled" to "false"

Comment: Check if module `auth` is defined, some where `angular.module('auth', [])` is required and is the module added to you app as dependency `angular.module('myApp', ['auth'])`. Then how and where have you added your app to your html markup with `ng-app="myApp"`. That could be reasons of not having the controller active. You could also add a `console.log('controller called');` at the top of your controller to see if it gets executed.

Comment: Yes the modules are declared in another file and they are correct, and the controller is being called correctly. But he is only seeing the varibles inside himself like the '$scope.signedIn' or the '$scope.logout' and not the variables inside the html..

Comment: If your form elements are set to disabled, no data will be read from them...

Comment: Ng-disabled only prevents from typing in it and not from getting data from it. And besides that not even the button 'Teste' is being seen..

Comment: Account.get() is an asynchronous call. It returns an empty object that will be populated later, when the response comes back. So you can't expect `account.user` to be defined right after executing the call.

Comment: BTW, the proper way to initialize $scope.user would be `$scope.user = {name: account.name, email: account.email}`. The way you're doing it will always fail.

Comment: Thats not what my problem is. And when i print the account its coming fine. The problem is that my controller is not seeing my variables declared in the ng-models of the html, nor the ng-click in the button 'Teste'.

Comment: ng-disabled acts just like a normal disabled attribute (with some additional functionality in being able to define directives).  A disabled form field will never get submitted.

Comment: there isn't enough code here to create a [mcve] and recreate your problem.

Comment: How can you set a value on `$scope.user.name` without defining `$scope.user` before? Are you sure you don't see errors in your developper console?

Comment: The "error" is exactly on this line, cant set variable name to undefined or something like this. Im the phone hard for me to describe with more details..

Comment: So... fix that error. I told you how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to have an object called user on the $scope:

```
$scope.user.
```

You have values tied to this object in the model.  You have to create this object yourself in your controller's constructor:

$scope.user = {};

Then your model bindings will populate things like
$scope.user.name on it from the input in the HTML.